# using github search api without specifying the repository or organization

Tags: github, github-api

I want to get a list of repositories or files where the contents of the files contained in the repositories match the keywords I specify in the search. I tried doing a simple search using https GET request and it looks like the search is not possible without specifying the repository or organization name. I get the below error.

```
https://api.github.com/search/code?q=authorization+in:file

{
  "message": "Validation Failed",
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Must include at least one user, organization, or repository",
      "resource": "Search",
      "field": "q",
      "code": "invalid"
    }
  ],
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-code"
}
```

I understand that searching without repository or organization name will be resource-intensive operation. Is there any work-around for this? I was assuming that since I am able to get results by using online search, I should be able to achieve the same using git search api.

So basically I am trying to simulate the below:

https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=authorization&type=Code&ref=searchresults

Comment: I think the documentation is not intact with the actual restrictions. Unfortunately. I also think your best shot for getting reliable answer in timely manner is to use official contact, and ask them specifically. And self-answer here.

Comment: @luk32 Yeah!  I will do that. I was just thinking if anybody has a better idea. I was thinking if any google search api could help. I could pass the website to search on and see if it works. Something like "keyword sites:github.com" we do in google search.  Sounds crazy but just giving it a thought ! Need to look for alternatives.

Comment: GitHub Community official: https://github.community/t/is-it-possible-to-global-search-with-api/122230/3 , you really need a Personal Access Token

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any work-around for this? I was assuming that since I am able to get results by using online search, I should be able to achieve the same using git search api.

The behavior you observed is expected for now -- you indeed need to specify a user, org or repository when using the code search API (something you don't need to do when using the Web UI), and currently there is no way around that.

https://developer.github.com/changes/2013-10-18-new-code-search-requirements/

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to get the stats only? Like, number of results, top 10 languages and how much of the results each, etc.?