# Search on Github repositories inside source files using API

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to use the search code from Github as presented in the following link:

[Search code](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-code)

They gave an example to search a "String" inside Github without the API as the following:

[search "amazing" in language:go](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=amazing%20language%3Ago&type=Code)

Is there a way to apply the last query to get results from the Rest API they are presenting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The help page mentions:

> The REST API supports the same qualifiers as GitHub.com.
> To learn more about the format of the query, see [Constructing a search query](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#constructing-a-search-query).
> See "[Searching code](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code/)" for a detailed list of qualifiers.

In your case:

```
curl -G https://api.github.com/search/code          \
--data-urlencode 'q=amazing language:go org:github' \
--data-urlencode 'sort=indexed'                   \
--data-urlencode 'order=desc'                     \
-H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.preview'
```

But: [since 2013](https://developer.github.com/changes/2013-10-18-new-code-search-requirements/), for an API search (not Web search), a [user, organization, or repository qualifier](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code#users-organizations-and-repositories) is now required, as [confirmed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28404275/6309).

This [thread mentions](https://github.community/t5/Project-Development-Help-and/Globally-searching-code-by-filename-via-APIv3/m-p/8417):

- [there currently isn't support for code searches using the GraphQL v4 API](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-API-Development-and/What-is-the-equivalent-graphQL-v4-api-query-for-v3-search-code/m-p/22101) (look for [GraphQL API v4 ChangeLog](https://developer.github.com/v4/changelog/))
- the "[Considerations for code search](https://help.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-code#considerations-for-code-search)", which specify searching by filename must include on search term, like '`amazing`' here.
  But it still needs, as [Nick K9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1749551/nick-k9) notes in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60538161/search-on-github-repositories-inside-source-files-using-api/60538667?noredirect=1#comment132125590_60538667), user and/or org and/or repo, to limit the search to a limited set of repositories (as I also mention in "[How do I programmatically extract GitHub repositories that contain a code string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74859941/6309)").

Comment: it gives me back this error "message": "Must include at least one user, organization, or repository"

Comment: @AmineBarrak Yes, I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: But why the result is not the same as the result in the URL: https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=amazing%20language%3Ago&type=Code

Comment: @AmineBarrak Yes, that is the point of my edit: through API, you cannot have the same result because of that constraint.

Comment: Though that you add a organisation "org:github", even with that we don't have results in the item. So the solution here is to parse the UI web page?

Comment: @AmineBarrak If you really need the same result than the Web UI, yes. But a GraphQL query would be more accurate.

Comment: I found something little bit similar ==> curl --user "username" https://api.github.com/search/code?q=amazing+language:go

Comment: Can you please share a solution with GraphQL?

Comment: @AmineBarrak Your similar solution would have the same limitation (adding  at least one user, organization, or repository)

Comment: @AmineBarrak I have edited the answer with additional information.

Comment: The request `api.github.com/search/code?q=filename:makefile` fails today with the same "at least one" error. The considerations say: "Except with filename searches, you must always include at least one search term when searching source code." Which I guess is not quite the same thing?

Comment: @NickK9 Exactly, and it must be limited to a set of repositories or, as I just mentioned, the result would be incomplete.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that IIUC your second bullet point says that you can search by filename without providing the scope, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @NickK9 OK I will edit to add the search term criteria.

Comment: Sorry, but that's still not accurate. This fails with the same "at least one" error: `https://api.github.com/search/code?q=filename:makefile%20PHONY`. I don't think any code searches are exempt from the "at least one user/org/repo" requirement.

Comment: @NickK9 Good point. I have edited the answer accordingly.