# How do I programmatically extract GitHub repositories that contain a code string?

Tags: github, github-api, pygithub, github-search

I am looking for a way to extract GitHub repositories containing files with a certain code string. I can do manually using the GitHub search bar. For instance, if I'm looking for the usages of the library pymc3 I could look for it in the search bar and then click on `Code`

[image]

How does one do this programmatically?

I tried going over the GitHub Search [API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/search?apiVersion=2022-11-28) documentation. The `Search Code` functionality allows looking into code but that seems to only search based on an user, organization, or repository. The `Search Repositories` functionality only looks into the description, title and README.

Update 1:

While browsing this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132790/how-to-search-for-code-in-github-with-github-api), I believe I found the answer to identify *some* repositories that contain a code string.

If I write the following code -

```
url = "https://api.github.com/search/code?q=pymc3 +in:file"

headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Token xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

I get the following result -

```
"total_count":43642,"incomplete_results":false,"items":[{"name":"pymc3_stoch_vol ...
```

However, the result gives me a bunch of information such as the git URL, HTML URL and *some* of the repositories that contain this string. I need to find a way to extract all the repositories that contain this string.

Update 2:

I now understand that GitHub limits results to 100 per page and 1000 results overall.

The only question remains why I didn't find this information on GitHub Search API documentation? Please do let me know if my understanding or the linked answer is wrong.

Comment: What about `/search/code`? See https://docs.github.com/en/rest/search?apiVersion=2022-11-28#search-code

Comment: I tried that, and I have explained the shortcomings of that :)

Comment: I assumed you meant something different with *Search Code* since this API is not restricted to search based on user/org/repo as far as I know. Why does `/search/code?q=pymc3` not give you the output you need?

Comment: When I try `https://api.github.com/search/code?q=pymc3`, I get the following error - `Must include at least one user, organization, or repository`

Comment: @Matt, I think I found a workaround the above problem. I have included the information inside update 1.

Comment: It is written [here](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/search?apiVersion=2022-11-28#about-search) that *«[...] the GitHub REST API provides up to 1,000 results for each search.»* The aspect concerning pagination (only 100 results per page) can be found [here](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/using-pagination-in-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of query should be addressed more by [GraphQL API](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql), but [searching code is still not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46317804/6309).

Only the [new code-search](https://github.com/features/code-search) ([presented here](https://github.blog/2022-11-15-a-better-way-to-search-navigate-and-understand-code-on-github/)) might be able to provide that, but:

- it is still in beta
- its API is not yet public.

So for now, code search in *all* GitHub repositories is not supported.

Comment: I see, but then why does the process work manually? As shown in the screenshot above, I was able to search for a string and it returned repositories that contained files using that string.

Comment: @desert_ranger Basically because *code* search on *all* repositories is not yet supported (probably because of the cost of such query). Its result, as you have seen, can only be incomplete, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62885607/6309).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should have clarified that I wanted the code search within the constraints given here - https://docs.github.com/en/rest/search?apiVersion=2022-11-28#search-code and not across all repositories. 

Please have a look at update 1 and 2 of my question. Everything is almost figured out :)

Comment: @desert_ranger Then the missing part of [pagination](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/using-pagination-in-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28)